# I am working on this code to allocate some memory and return pointer, but I am getting segmentation fault error

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working on this code to allocate some memory and return pointer, but I am getting segmentation fault error. Please help me figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "memalloc.h"
int total_holes,sizeofmemory;
void* start_of_memory;
void setup( int malloc_type, int mem_size, void* start_of_memory ) {
/**
 *  Fill your code here
 *
**/
    sizeofmemory=mem_size;
    //initionlize memory
    start_of_memory = (int *) malloc(mem_size*sizeof(int));
    if(malloc_type==0)
    {
        //first of
        printf("first fit");
        void firstfit();
    }
    else if(malloc_type==1)
    {
        //first of
        printf("best fit");
        void bestfit();
    }
    else if(malloc_type==2)
    {
        //first of
        printf("worst fit of");
        void worstfit();
    }
    else if(malloc_type==3)
    {
        //first of
        printf("Buddy system");
        void buddyfit();
    }


}

void *my_malloc(int size) {
/**
 *  Fill your code here
 *
**/

    //chek pointer in null or not
    if((start_of_memory = malloc(size)) == NULL) {
        printf("no memory reserve");
        }
        else{
            //add more memory in void pointer

            start_of_memory=start_of_memory+size;
        }           
    return (void*)-1;
}

void my_free(void *ptr) {
/**
 *  Fill your code here
 *
**/
    free(ptr);
}

int num_free_bytes() {
/**
 *  Fill your code here
 *
**/
    //count number of free bytes i
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<sizeofmemory;i++)
    {
        if(start_of_memory+i==0)
        {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int num_holes() {
/**
 *  Fill your code here
 *
**/
    // call function num_free_bytes and check free space
    total_holes=num_free_bytes();
    return total_holes;
}
//memalloc.h

void setup(int malloc_type, int mem_size, void* start_of_memory);
void *my_malloc(int size);
void my_free(void* ptr);
int num_free_bytes();
int num_holes();
#define FIRST_FIT       0
#define BEST_FIT        1
#define WORST_FIT       2
#define BUDDY_SYSTEM    3
```

Comment: `my_malloc` always returns -1

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

The code below is possibly closer to what you want. Usually custom malloc function returns pointer to the beginning of the allocated memory not to the end of it. Your original function never returns any allocated memory but 
    `(void *)(-1)`

```
void *my_malloc(int size) {
 void * start_of_memory;
//check pointer if null or not
if((start_of_memory = (void *)malloc(size)) == NULL) {
    printf("no memory reserve");
        return NULL; // no memory 
    }
    else{     
        return (start_of_memory); 
    }
```

}

Comment: +sg7                  But the programme still crashes after running a few simulations...if you could help...that would be great...

Comment: @YasirMehmood - post your `main` and I can take a look.

Comment: What's with the cast of `malloc()` which already returns a void pointer? I've seen people cast it to `int *` or `char *` or `struct name *` but they are discouraged from doing so. When `malloc` fails to reserve memory, it returns NULL, which is subsequently assigned to `start_of_memory`. Do you really need to have 2 different return statement though `start_of_memory` will contain either a NULL or a memory location?

Comment: @alvits 1) You are very right!  In C, you don't need to cast the return value of malloc . The pointer to void returned by malloc is automagically converted to the correct type. However, if you want your code to compile with a C++ compiler, a cast is needed. 2) `start_of_memory` will contain either a NULL or a memory location - TRUE! I just kept code close to the original since @Yasir Mehmood wanted to distinguish these two scenarios and print `"no memory..."`. Thank you for looking at the code.